# Анимация в svg c атрибутами d и transform

Tags: svg, svg-animation

Дано: четыре файла `svg` с одинаковой структурой. В каждой `svg` есть 4 `path`. Отличаются они только атрибутами d и `transform`.

Проблема: В атрибуте `transform`, в нем повторяется дважды translate:

```
transform="translate(2004.586538, 563.741494) rotate(26.000000) translate(-2004.586538, -563.741494)
```

Как такое анимировать?
Мои пробы:

```
<animate xlink:href="#p1" attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" 
    values = "M841.586538,-88.7585061 L3167.58654,-88.7585061 L3167.58654,1216.24149 L1141.58654,1216.24149 C975.901113,1216.24149 841.586538,1081.92692 841.586538,916.241494 L841.586538,-88.7585061 Z; M957.745625,-1216.57773 L3283.74563,-1216.57773 L3283.74563,88.4222735 L1257.74563,88.4222735 C1092.0602,88.4222735 957.745625,-45.8923016 957.745625,-211.577727 L957.745625,-1216.57773 Z" 
    dur="10s" 
    repeatCount="indefinite" 
    fill="freeze" />

<animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
      type="translate" values="2004.586538, 563.741494; 2120.745625, -564.077727" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="4s" fill="freeze" additive="sum"/>

<animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
      type="rotate" values="26.000000; -22.000000" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="4s" fill="freeze" additive="sum"/>
```

[Ссылка на четыре SVG](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvjMob)

[Видео желаемого результата. Смотреть до 12 секунды](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WGhQo5E_qkheOszb6goJI9fk-a4OWj8t/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: анимировать не проблема, проблема понять из описания, что вам нужно подучить на выходе? Какое положение элементов будет на финише. Добавьте такую картинку или если возможно точно опишите словами. Но лучше картинку, слова понимаются по разному :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, обновил, прошу посмотреть, возможно Вы моя последняя надежда ;-)

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/Afyai По ссылке этот файл я не могу скачать

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, обновил)

Comment: забрал видео файл

Comment: посмотрел видео, думаю анимация получится. Быстро не обещаю, но заглядывайте почаще :))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, жду. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Решил перерисовать полностью ваш SVG/ В таком виде, как у вас сделано,  анимировать будет очень проблематично. Повторю все формы фигуры и анимацию, как на видео файле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если так подумать то мы можем сложить 4 `rect` с `ry="20"` и выставить их за `viewBox` а под них положить какой то фон ..в вашем случае это обычная какая то штука которую мне лень было рисовать и я под них положил обычное фото а анимация это даже не `smil` это обычная css3 анимация ..мы крутим группу закруглённых квадратов ..и всё смотрим дэмо

А то что все квадраты в группе не вылазиют это разумеется - они за `viewBox`

Тоже самое можно сделать и path тоже крутить придётся всё равно группу

```css
.group {
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  animation: r 20s linear infinite;
}

.group rect {
  fill: #7f26e1;
}

@keyframes r {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(20deg)translateX(50px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(120deg)translate(70px, -20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 304 234 228" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<image  width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="304" href="https://www.tokkoro.com/picsup/5226413-perspective-architetcure-building-building-exterior-exterior-blue-sky-lines-skyscraper-sky-window-architecture-tower-office-skyscraper-lines-window-view-cyan-urban-turquoise-teal-highrise-publ.jpg" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
<g fill="#f00" class="group">
   <rect transform="rotate(44.206037)" x="109.35448" y="-3.4432883" width="214.69048" height="212.42261" rx="20" ry="20" style="paint-order:fill markers stroke"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(44.206037)" x="327.77579" y="-2.6431608" width="214.69048" height="212.42261" rx="20" ry="20" style="paint-order:fill markers stroke"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(44.206037)" x="107.41637" y="213.81729" width="214.69048" height="212.42261" rx="20" ry="20" style="paint-order:fill markers stroke"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(44.206037)" x="326.22729" y="213.50017" width="214.69048" height="212.42261" rx="20" ry="20" style="paint-order:fill markers stroke"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Я вот в этом примере попытался показать как реализуется этот эффект - смотрите на весь экран:

```css
body{
  background: tomato;
}

.items{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.viewBox{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.viewBox img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.outer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  animation: routing 20s linear infinite;
}

.outer .item{
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.item:nth-child(1){
  position: absolute;
  left: -805px;
  top: -805px;
}

.item:nth-child(2){
  position: absolute;
  right: -805px;
  top: -805px;
}

.item:nth-child(3){
  position: absolute;
  left: -805px;
  bottom: -805px;
}

.item:nth-child(4){
  position: absolute;
  right: -805px;
  bottom: -805px;
}

@keyframes routing{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(30deg)translate(20px, 100px);
  }
  50%{
    transform: rotate(-10deg)translate(-20px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="viewBox">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnd7m.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно Вас понял.....

```
<animateTransform 
xlink:href="#path7056"
attributeName = "transform"
type = "translate"
from="150 20"
to="0 0"
dur="0.4s"
begin="1s"
fill="freeze"/>
```